# two way dialog between Nodejs tcp server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

What is the correct way to have two way dialog between client and tcp server in nodejs?

What I'm doing using the net module:

```
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
//server will receive some sequence of data, and it should 
  respond with a response to each message

socket.on('data', function(data){

//read and interpret data using string comparison

socket.write("some message");
});
```

When I do this, I get a timeout, so I thought I needed to indicate when I am done by using `socket.end()` after I call `socket.write()`. But if I do that, I get a 'write after end exception'

Comment: `socket.write()` will send the data.  I think we'll need to see a bunch more of the context of the code and perhaps see both client and server code to know how to help.

Comment: You may find socket.io a lot simpler to use because it's a higher level transport that lets you send messages and data and it handles all the packing and parsing for you.  With plain TCP, you have to invent your own protocol and parse the incoming data into discrete units that your code can do something with.  Data can arrive in pieces and you have to assemble those pieces properly, understand where boundaries are between messages, etc...  socket.io does all that for you.